# Show that the two functions are equal

Tags: analysis

so i spend quite some time finding out why
$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^x(t-x)}{2 \sinh(t)} \frac{a^2+x^2}{a^2+t^2} dt= \frac{xa^{x-1}}{2} (a^2+x^2) \left(\frac{a}{x} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{x+1}}{\sinh(at)} \frac{1}{1+t^2} dt - \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{x}}{\sinh(at)} \frac{1}{1+t^2} dt  \right)$ for $a,x>0$
Does someone have a hint on how to show that?

Answer (score 0):

Let $$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{t^x(t-x)(a^2+x^2)}{2(\sinh t) (a^2+t^2)} \, dt= \frac{a^2+x^2}2\int_0^\infty \frac{t^x(t-x)}{(\sinh t) (a^2+t^2)} \, dt .$$ Making the change of variable $t=a\tau$ gives \begin{align*} \int_0^\infty \frac{t^x(t-x)}{(\sinh t) (a^2+t^2)} \, dt &= \int_0^\infty \frac{((a\tau)^x(a\tau-x)}{(\sinh (a\tau)) (a^2+a^2\tau^2)} \cdot a \, d\tau \\
&=a^{x-1} \int_0^\infty \frac{\tau^x(a\tau-x)}{(\sin(a\tau))(1+\tau^2)}\, d\tau\\
&=a^{x-1} \bigg (a\int_0^\infty \frac{\tau^{x+1}}{(\sin(a\tau))(1+\tau^2)}\, d\tau-x\int_0^\infty \frac{\tau^x}{(\sin(a\tau))(1+\tau^2)}\, d\tau \bigg )\\
&= xa^{x-1} \bigg (\frac a x \int_0^\infty \frac{\tau^{x+1}}{(\sin(a\tau))(1+\tau^2)}\, d\tau-\int_0^\infty \frac{\tau^x}{(\sin(a\tau))(1+\tau^2)}\, d\tau \bigg ).
\end{align*} Substituting this back into the second formula for $I$ gives the answer.